i18next not loading in chrome extension
I am trying to add internationalization and dynamic language change in the chrome extension. This is not possible using chrome.i18n API. So I am using i18next with react-i18next. I have configured the language support in a way that it is possible to change the language at runtime using dropdown.
However, I am not able to load the extension in the browser(chrome) after making a build.
Here is the popup I encountered.

import i18n from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";

import StorageLocal from "@common/storage-local";

import * as translationDE from "../../../static/_locales/de/messages.json";
import * as translationEN from "../../../static/_locales/en/messages.json";
import * as translationES from "../../../static/_locales/es/messages.json";
import * as translationFR from "../../../static/_locales/fr/messages.json";
import * as translationJA from "../../../static/_locales/ja/messages.json";
import * as translationZH from "../../../static/_locales/zh/messages.json";

const resources = {
    en: {
        translation: translationEN.default,
    },
    fr: {
        translation: translationFR.default,
    },
    de: {
        translation: translationDE.default,
    },
    es: {
        translation: translationES.default,
    },
    ja: {
        translation: translationJA.default,
    },
    zh: {
        translation: translationZH.default,
    },
};

const localLang = async () => {
    return (await StorageLocal.get("newTabExtensionLanguage"))
        .newTabExtensionLanguage;
};

localLang()
    .then((data) => {
        let extLang = "en";
        const supportedLanguages = ["en", "fr", "es", "de", "ja", "zh"];
        if (supportedLanguages.includes(data.substring(0, 2))) {
            extLang = data.substring(0, 2);
        }
        // tslint:disable-next-line: no-floating-promises
        i18n.use(initReactI18next) // passes i18n down to react-i18next
            .init({
                resources,
                lng: extLang,

                keySeparator: false, // we do not use keys in form messages.welcome

                interpolation: {
                    escapeValue: false, // react already safes from xss
                },
            });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });

export default i18n;

I tried removing the key mentioned from all the translation file but it's just leads to removal of other keys and it goes on.
With using chrome.i18n API we are not able to change the langague dynamically.
